# Populate Missing Data is SQL with CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I am stuck with a problem related to SQL while implementing data densification.

I have a table containing weather data for different stations. This table updates every 10 minutes. But sometimes not all the station data is available after the 10 minute update. Additionally, I want to drill down it's granularity to 1 minute i.e all data points should be available every minute.

I have implemented a CTE to make a column of DateTime with 1 minute granularity. Now I need to populate the NULL values with the station names and sum of rainfall data wrt to it's station name and previous data.

I am trying to use windowing partition functions but it's not working out yet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vytpl.png)

The SQL query is this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DateTime = '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000',
        @ToDate   DateTime = '2021-08-01 00:00:00.000'

;WITH DateCte (DateTime) AS
(
    SELECT @FromDate 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, DateTime)
    FROM DateCte
    WHERE DateTime < @ToDate
)
SELECT
    DateTime,
    DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, [LastObservations].[Local_Time]), 0) AS [Local Time],
    [LastObservations].[Name_En],
    [LastObservations].[Rainfall] AS [Value]
FROM
    DateCte
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [ODW].[QMD].[LastObservations] ON DateCte.DateTime = DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, [LastObservations].[Local_Time]), 0) 
                                   AND [LastObservations].[Local_Time] >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                                   AND [LastObservations].[Local_Time] <= '2021-08-01 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY 
    DateCte.DateTime
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Add sample data and expected results as consumable *text*, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Good day, You speak about tables but you only present images and we cannot query the content of image! Please provide queries to create your table and to insert sample data + describe the expected result according to that sample data.